# Setting a variable value after super.initState but Flutter still tries to run without it

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I am declaring a variable called `localDB` using the `late` keyword. I then use a function to give it a value. Once this value is set, I should be able to run `db.sqlDeleteAllRows(db: localDB, table: StaticGlobals.sqlTableName)`, but it is giving me an error: `LateInitializationError: Field 'localDB' has not been initialized.` On the physical device, the app shows a red screen with an error, but then immediately it clears the error and shows the screen like normal. It's almost as if this error is only appearing on the very first build of the widget but not on future ones.

Basically, this widget is a wrapper over the entire app that looks at Firebase auth changes. If the user ever logs out, then I want to clear the sqflite table I have. How do I make it so that I can do this without Flutter struggling with this variable?

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Wrapper> createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  final db = Database();
  late sql.Database localDB;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    localDB = await db.initSQL();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: initialize(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        return Consumer<ModelAuthUser?>(
          builder: (context, value, child) {
            if (value?.uid == null) {
              db.sqlDeleteAllRows(db: localDB, table: StaticGlobals.sqlTableName);
              return const Authenticate();
            } else {
              return const Home();
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Because you are performing an `async` operation in `initState` and an `async` operation takes time.

Try wrapping your consumer with the `FutureBuilder` so that it uses your localDB value after it is `initialized`

Now what is happening is you are using your localDB value before it is `initialized`.

```
late int counter;

Future<bool> initialize() async {
// time taken to initialze your db value
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
counter = 10;
// your db value is initialzed now so return something like bool 
here.
return true;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: initialize(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) 
  {
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
    return Center(child: Text(counter.toString()),);
    }
    else{
      return Center(child: Text("Loading"),);
    }
    },
   );
  }
```

You can also run it here to get the idea [Working example](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zoi06yzpj06?split=50&lazy=false&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart)

Comment: Ok I added the `FutureBuilder` around my `Consumer` widget and passed in the `future: initialize()` argument. I don't see the red screen on the app anymore but the same error still appears in the Run tab of Android Studio

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Please add the code you updated in the question.

Comment: Ok I updated my question with the latest code.

Comment: don't call the initialize method in initState now when you are using FutureBuilder

Comment: I have updated the answer and you can refer to it, You have to do something like this in your code because you can't use late value before initializing, so you have to wait for it to be initialized.